# How to create "Coderwall" Pane? Use Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

To be quick I would like to create something like this here:

https://coderwall.com/p/wjz4xa

Important: This link above links to a single modal page. If you visit https://coderwall.com you can click on one of the posts and you will see the modal appearing.

I dont want you to write any code for me. I would just like to have some tips on how to go about this. I am not even sure what to look for on google.

I am used to for instance the bootstrap modal but I am not sure whether using this will help me come close to the example on coderwall. Furthermore, bootstrap does not feature having a specific URI to link to one single modal.

It would be great, if you could just give me some quick tips on this topic.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

just add a opaque background color to your modal
`background-color: rgb(0,0,0);`

```
<div class="modal fade" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and when having the static 'modal' page copy the modal's style